# Different methods of completing an "empty" async Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm using a library that has both a synchronous and an `async` version of a `Reconcile` method.

The methods take 2 `IEnumerables`, and 3 delegates that get called for items that are Added, Modified, or Deleted from the 2nd list based on values from the first.

My code is currently working with the synchronous version, and I'd like to convert it to using the `async` version.

Since I don't actually need to do any work in the delegate for deleting, I'm passing in `(item) => {}` for the `deletedAction` argument.

I've found several different versions of how to convert that in to an "empty" async delegate scattered around the internet, and across StackOverflow, but I'm not sure of the difference between them, or which way is the most correct.

What are the differences between these methods of sending an "empty" async delegate as an argument, and which of them is the current "most correct" way?  Is there a better way that I have missed?

1. `async (item) => {await Task.CompletedTask;}`
2. `async (item) => {await Task.FromResult(0);}`
3. `async (item) => {await Task.Yield;}`
4. `async (item) => {await Task.Delay(0);}` (this one seems like a bad choice, but I'm including it for completeness)

They all seem to be working, except for `Task.CompletedTask`, but that is because the framework I'm using is the 4.5 version of the .Net Framework, and it doesn't exist in that version.

Comment: If you don't need to do any work then why not pass in a `null` or have an overload that doesn't take it at all?

Comment: @DavidG It's a method in a 3rd-party library that I don't have control over.

Comment: @Liam It *is* `async` all the way down.

Comment: And it exploded if you pass in null?

Comment: The most correct way is `item => Task.CompletedTask` or `item => Task.FromResult(0)` (if you cannot use `CompletedTask`). There is no reason to add `async` and `await` there.

Comment: @DavidG yes, it is throwing an exception if I pass `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So none of them are correct.  What you should be doing is:

```
item => Task.CompletedTask
```

Or, when on an older version of the framework:

```
item => Task.FromResult(0)
```

You have no reason to make the method `async` just to await an already completed task.  It's just adding overhead of the state machine in order to accomplish nothing.

Using `Delay` is just going through an extra layer of indirection before returning a completed task.  It's adding nothing useful except obscuring the fact that you're trying to return a completed `Task`.  It's also relying on an undocumented implementation detail that `Delay` returns a completed task when the timeout is `0`, which is something to be avoided where possible.

Using `Yield` is by far the worst.  The whole *point* of `Yield` is that it won't be observed as being completed right away.  The *goal* of `Yield` is to result in the continuation being added and fired, rather than the task being observed as being completed immediately.  It exists specifically to avoid the optimization *that you want to take advantage of*.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what's going on with `Task.Yield`, it is essentially creating an additional state in the state-machine that an `async` method gets compiled in to; almost like a marker in the method that says "You can go back to what you were doing, but  continue executing from here the next time you get a chance"?